# Calling informatica workflow from java/jsp/servlets

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I need to trigger an informatica workflow on the click of a button in my web application.
Is this possible?
if Yes how? if no then is there any alternative way of doing it(Like calling a shell script)?

Answer (score 3):

Informatica has a shell command called pmcmd which you could use to start and stop workflows. If you have the product documentation then look into the document "Command Line Interface". You could call that command from a shell from within your java program.

Comment: I must also point that Informatica has added a java api with an SDK starting from version 9.5.